# Seat clamp tolerance

Tags: seatpost, clamp

Manufacturer specifies a seat clamp/collar size of 36.6mm. I was wondering if a 36.4mm clamp will work?

How much tolerance is there with a seat clamp?

Comment: Anecdotally, a seatpost that's not a good fit is really creaky and annoying. Not sure how far mine was out, but it drove me nuts and had to be tightened up far to tight.

Comment: If you're talking purely about the collar, there is probably at least 1mm of "play".  The seat tube, OTOH, will not have as much, but likely will have 0.2mm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

0.2mm on seatpost clamp will make no difference!
The tolerence is small maybe 1-2mm. a 0.2mm difference is pretty much how far the clamp moves when you tighten the binder! maybe even more.
Youll see how far it moves when you take the binder off the frame and tighten it a little. the clamp goes smaller basically clamping down. so in practice it clamps the seat tube down onto the seatpost tightening all in its place. long explanation, I know but thats the just of it.